# Lumen - authentication with remember me option

Tags: authentication, lumen

Following the Lumen doc (http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/authentication), I'm successfully authenticating my website users with the following code :

```
if( Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password') ) ) {
  // success
}
```

But I can't get the remember me functionnality working properly. This is my code :

```
$remember = (bool) $request->input('remember');
if( Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'),$remember ) ) {
  // success
}
```

And my database "users" table has a column named remember_token, which is a varchar(100) NULL (mysql).

The users are still being authenticated successfully but the remember_token is not filled (always null) and my users are not remembered.

How can I make it work?